# Replace string that contains CRLF?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm reformatting a file, and I want to perform the following steps:

1. Replace double CRLF's with a temporary character sequence (`$CRLF$` or something)
2. Remove all CRLF's in the whole file
3. Go back and replace the double CRLF's.

So input like this:

```
This is a paragraph
of text that has
been manually fitted
into a certain colum
width.

This is another
paragraph of text
that is the same.
```

Will become

```
This is a paragraph of text that has been manually fitted into a certain colum width.

This is another paragraph of text that is the same.
```

It seems this should be possible by piping the input through a few simple `sed` programs, but I'm not sure how to refer to `CRLF` in `sed` (to use in `sed 's/<CRLF><CRLF>/$CRLF$/'`). Or maybe there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: `s//` operates on lines. You cannot change `\r\n` with it. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n).

Comment: @Banthar Thanks, however it seems you can still use `sed`, in the method described in the answer?

Comment: Are they actually carriage returns and line-feeds (Windows-style) or are they Unix-style newlines?

Comment: They are using sed to combine the lines together. If you can use perl try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1252020/745924). You should be able to do the whole thing in a single run.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Windows-style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sed to decorate all rows with a {CRLF} at end:

```
sed 's/$/<CRLF>/'
```

then remove all \r\n with tr

```
| tr -d "\r\n"
```

and then replace double CRLF's with \n

```
| sed 's/<CRLF><CRLF>/\n/g'
```

and remove leftover CRLF's.

There was an one-liner sed which did all this in a single cycle, but I can't seem to find it now.

Comment: This works exactly as I require, here's the final program I used: `sed -e 's/$/<CRLF>/' $* | tr -d "\r\n" | sed 's/<CRLF><CRLF>/\n\n/g' | sed 's/<CRLF>[ \t]*/ /g'`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/$/ /;s/^ *$/CRLF/' | tr -d '\r\n' | sed 's/CRLF/\r\n'/
```

That's not quite the method you've given; what this does is the below:

1. Add a space to the end of each line.
2. Replace any line that contains only whitespace (ie blank lines) with "CRLF".
3. Deletes any line-breaking characters (both CR and LF).
4. Replaces any occurrences of the string "CRLF" with a Windows-style line break.

This works on Cygwin bash for me.

Answer (score 0):

#### Redefine the Problem

It looks like what you're *really* trying to do is reflow your paragraphs and single-space your lines. There are a number of ways you can do this.

#### A Non-Sed Solution

If you don't mind using some packages outside coreutils, you could use some additional shell utilities to make this as easy as:

```
dos2unix /tmp/foo
fmt -w0 /tmp/foo | cat --squeeze-blank | sponge /tmp/foo
unix2dos /tmp/foo
```

Sponge is from the *moreutils* package, and will allow you to write the same file you're reading. The *dos2unix* (or alternatively the *tofrodos*) package will allow to convert your line endings back and forth for easier integration with tools that expect Unix-style line endings.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!{N;/\n$/{p;d};s/\r\?\n/ /;ba}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing why this is not easier?

Add CRLF:

> sed -e s/\s+$/$'\r\n'/ < index.html > index_CRLF.html

remove CRLF... go unix:

> sed -e s/\s+$/$'\n'/ < index_CRLF.html > index.html